# Grep Before and After Last '/'

Tags: linux, bash, unix, grep

Im Trying to Write a Script That Echo String Before and After The '/'

Example Input

```
/Library/Users/foo.txt
```

Now I Need Two Outputs

1. `/Library/Users`
2. `foo.txt`

How Can i Get Those Outputs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `dirname` and `basename`:

```
$ dirname /Library/Users/foo.txt
/Library/Users
$ basename /Library/Users/foo.txt
foo.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

dirname & basename are standalone programs in /bin.  This can be done much more efficiently, entirely within bash using the builtin variable substitution -- no needless execs to dirname or basename.

Use ${*var%re*} to strip trailing regular-expression from *var*, and use ${*var##re*} to strip re from the beginning of var:

```
$ path=/Libarary/Users/foo.txt
$ dir=${path%/*}
$ base=${path##*/} 
$ echo $path : basename is $base and dir is $dir
/Library/Users/foo.txt : basename is foo.txt and dir is /Library/Users
```

Comment: Note that `dirname` and `${path%/*}` produce different results if `x` ends in a trailing `/`. I would still use parameter expansion if I was confident that `path` was a path to a file (not a directory), or that there would be no trailing `/`, but it's still something to be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`

```
awk -F/ '{$NF=x;sub(/\/$/,x)}1' OFS=/
/Library/Users
```

```
awk -F/ '{print $NF}'
foo.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

falsetru's answer will start 2 processes. If performance is an issue
parameter substitution can be used, e.g.

```
path="/Library/Users/foo.txt"

dir="${path%/*}"
base="${path##*/}"
```

or

```
echo "${path%/*}"
echo "${path##*/}"
```